# How do I decorate (time) a Task in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, task

I have a service similar to:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public Task<string> GetData()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var str = client.GetStringAsync("http://www.example.com");
        return str;
    }
    //...
}
```

Now, using the decorator pattern I want to time this method

```
public class TimedService : IService
{
    private readonly IService _service;

    public TimedService(IService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public Task<string> GetData()
    {
        using(var timer = new TimerContext())
            return _service.GetData();
    }
}
```

The `TimerContext` starts timing after it's constructed and stops it on disposal and publishes it into some kind of log, not needing to have the measured time returned.

Now using the above approach does not time the real execution time of the task but the mere creation and retrieval of the `Task` instance.

How do I return a `Task` from the TimedService which, when run, will start the timer, execute the original `Task` (from the real `Service` class) and the dispose the timer?

Comment: You could use a stopawtch and return a Task<tuple<string,int>> where int is the elapsed time it took to run.

Comment: You may pass the `TimerContext` in `_service.GetData()` and dispose it manually, if it is suitable for you.

Comment: @Vyrira: Yes I could but that would defeat the purpose of separating the concerns (i.e. have the concern of timing in the `TimedService` class and the concern of actually getting the data in the `Service` class)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make the method `async` and `await` the `Task`.

```
public async Task<string> GetData()
{
    using(var timer = new TimerContext())
        return await _service.GetData();
}
```

Now `timer` will be disposed *when `GetData` has completed*, rather than as soon as it has been *started*.